# Why are empty lines being generated in orbeon's source code for forms?

Tags: orbeon, blank-line

When working with a complicated form in the orbeon form builder and checking the source code, I see that there are huge amounts of empty lines added. This causes the code to grow from about 20k lines of code to even 10 times larger, 200k(!). What could be the reason for producing so many redundant white lines?

Answer (score 0):

We fixed recently issue [#1956](https://github.com/orbeon/orbeon-forms/issues/1956), which is available in Orbeon Forms 4.8. You could try 4.8 and see if that fixes the problem for you. (This doesn't rule out that there could be other issues.)